# Win 10 Wake Timer works only when put to sleept with "sleep" button but not with sleep.bat

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler, wake-up

cmd' file to put my computer to sleep:

```
rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0
```

If I run the 'sleep.cmd' file the computer goes to sleep and I can wake it up by pressing a key on the keyboard or clicking the mouse.

BUT: 
Wake Timers do not work anymore:
[image]

If I put the computer to sleep with 'start menu -> Power -> Sleep ' 
then the same wake timer I set with the Windows Task Scheduler works.

Does someone know if I have to change my command in the 'sleep.cmd' file or if I can add another command that I am maybe missing that also wake timers can wake up ?

WAKE ON LAN works with both ways ( 'sleep' Button in StartMenu and 'sleep.cmd' file )

Answer (score 0):

Ok I can answer my own question:

With the `PsShutdown` utility it works !

Just  [Download PsTools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psshutdown) (microsoft sysinternals) extract and add the target extraction folder to your windows 'PATH' variable.

Then you have to run your target **sleep.cmd** script as administrator, call the `PsShutdown` executable (that is in your path variable or use an absolute folder path ) and it works:

- -d   => Suspend the computer
- -t => 0 seconds until computer gets suspended

[image]